# Creating my first App inside Office 365, are there any App catalog site collections created for us

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

I am starting a new SharePoint Office 365 project. now i want to develop an App inside the SP online. currently i got those sites :-

[image]

so i am not sure if i want to create a new APP where i need to deploy it? now on the on-premises farms there is a section to create an app catalog site, where i deploy my apps and then i add the related apps inside the related site collections. but inside my Office 365 i can not find this option??
Can anyone adivce on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in SPO, we have a Site Catalog available. Since, its a fresh tenant, you will have to create an app catalog site first and then you can upload apps there.

To do that, go to the Sharepoint admin center.

There you will find the apps section as below:

[image]

Once you click on it, you will get an option to create the app catalog site.

Here enter the details as required and it will create app catalog site collection(takes some time to get created)

[image]

Once its done, it will show up in the list of collections(see below image) and you will be able to upload the apps there.

Please be patient regarding this as it takes sometime to get created. Some time back on a fresh tenant, it took 45 mins.

[image]

Comment: So in this case i can start developing apps (what i mainly need is to develop some remote event receivers which get fired when i add/edit/delete list items)?? or still i need to purchase/configure the app domain inside office 365? as on the on-premises i need to configure DNS to allow deploying apps? now when i develop a remote event receiver i will have 2 projects inside the visual studio project:- 1) the SP one 2) and the provided host one... so can i deploy this inside our office 365?

Comment: sorry, this is out of scope for the question. For your case (event receivers), you have 2 options, deploy to azure or deploy to IIS (your on-prem server). So, you web(provider hosted one) can be deployed to azure or IIS. If you have azure, you can deploy there, if you have IIS, you can deploy there. Its your choice. The Sharepoint project(.app) file should be uploaded in this app catalog site. I have seen your featured question, will attempt to answer it over the weekend :)

Comment: I do not want to develop Event Receiver (server side), i want to develop Remote Event Receivers. as i am using Office 365 sharepoint. so local IIS is not an option for me. now i can create the Remote Event Receiver using VS 2012 and create the .app file...then can i upload the .app file to the app catalog site collection inside Office 365?is this all what i need ? OR since RER require to be implemented as provider hosted app then i will need to purchase Azure to host my RER ???

Comment: RERs can be hosted on local IIS as well as azure. If you have IIS, you can use that, else purchase azure subscription and deploy there.
Once the app file is created, you can upload it to app catalog.

Comment: so you mean even if i want to use develop remote event receivers for my sharepoint online then i can host it inside local IIS which is exposed to the internet ?

Comment: yes, thats correct.

Comment: so i can use any IIS ,, i mean the host does not have to be a sharepoint server ??? Second question now if the RER will be hosted inside external IIS (or Azure) then why do i need to add the .app file o the office 365 app catalog ??

Comment: 1) Yes, any IIS, need not even be Sharepoint server. 2) out of scope for this question.